# Chart.js 2 - Always display only some tooltips in bubble chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, chart.js, chart.js2

I work with chart js **version 2.5.0**. I have a bubble chart and I would like that when a bubble is clicked, it keep the tooltip corresponding remains displayed.
I tried to make a plugin, in which it is enough to add a `keepTooltipOpen` parameter in the data like that:

```
datasets: [{
        type: 'bubble',
        label: "set2",
        data: [{
          x: 14,
          y: 30,
          r: 60,
          //Here is the added parameter.
          keepTooltipOpen: true
        }, {
          x: 2,
          y: 5,
          r: 30
        }]
```

**You can find the [Fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/bencarbon/5axta20L/4/)** There is an error in `afterDatasetsDraw`when the tooltip is update. Open web console to see it.

Someone have a suggestion to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In chart.js version 2.5.0, you need to write `_options: chart.options.tooltips,`instead of `_options: chart.options,`.

[New Fiddle is here.](https://jsfiddle.net/bencarbon/5axta20L/9/)